# How can show MDiChild form as Modal?

Tags: vb6

When I try show form take this error "MDI child forms cannot be show modally".  Can Someone help me?

Ty

Comment: You cannot do so. MDI child forms cannot be shown modally; it defeats the entire purpose of using MDI. If you need to show it modally, don't make it an MDI child. (MDI is "Multiple Document Interface", which means you're supposed to allow **multiple documents** at the same time - if you show the form's modally, it's a "single document interface", which would make it SDI instead.)

Comment: Let me try say what I need, when I showed MDI Child o code keep running I need it stop how happen it showed with vbmodal.

Comment: Then do what I said: Don't use an MDI child form. If you need things to stop running while the form is displayed, you need a modal form, but you **cannot** use an MDI child form. I don't know how else to say this so it is clear: You **can not** use an MDI child form as a modal form, so you may as well stop trying.

Comment: I Understand you point and your need. Sometimes we have some information usually displayed as child. Product detail for example. Then, during a process we need to show this information e=and continue. We should use the same form. Unfortunally there is no this option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show that form as a modal form - it just isn't allowed. However, as a work-around, you could put the GUI of the current form into a UserControl. You then put the UserControl in your MDI Child form, so that it resizes to fill the form. Likewise, you can create a different, non-MDI form to contain the UserControl when you want to show it as a dialogue.

Comment: Using the UserControl is a kludgy hack. The proper solution is to use a non-MDI child window that you can properly show modally without needing to use a kludge to get around your poor design decisions.

Comment: @KenWhite I disagree. A UserControl is a container for an element of GUI functionality. I can't see why this is a poor design-decision. Indeed, this is the only way that you can dynamically load a library of VB dialogue boxes (GUI implemented as UserControls) into an EXE, and have the windows be part of the same Forms collection.

Comment: Using a UserControl to work around the fact that an MDI child form is not supposed to be displayed modally (which means it's violating the entire designed functionality of MDI) is a kludge. If you need a form to display modally in a MDI application, **don't make the modal window an MDI child window**, because it isn't one.